# Remove special characters in scrapy xpath

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

Cannot seem to accomplish after many hours.  I am trying to edit a script.

Price from `scrapy = $123,456`
I need 123456 instead.

I have tried this but get attribute errors and more.

```
price_txt = response.xpath(".//dt[contains(text(), 'List Price')]/following-sibling::dd/text()").extract_first()


price = price_txt.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '.,$()'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .replace()

```
price_txt = response.xpath(".//dt[contains(text(), 'List Price')]/following-sibling::dd/text()").extract_first()


price = price_txt.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')
```

Comment: Excellent.  Very simple and easy.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

price_txt = "$123,456"
print(re.sub(r"[^\d]", "", price_txt))
```

---

Or `str.isdigit`

**Ex:**

```
print("".join(i for i in price_txt if i.isdigit()))
```

**Output:**

```
123456
123456
```